# how to copy e all the data loop variable produce?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have code which counts each word occurrence means how many each word appears in the string.

I want to copy all the count data to the new file

```
for w in `cat tes.txt`; do echo $w; done | cp w test.txt
```

in test.txt file,  only the result total line shows up and nothing

Comment: show us test sample data

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, this is what I am getting 10681

Comment: that pipe should be used inside the for loop

Comment: what should you be getting rather than the number you just posted?

Comment: A better way would be to use the tee command `for w in $(cat list.txt); do echo "$w" | tee -a text.txt; done`

Comment: this is working but it is very very slow. it took 5 mins to complete the process